# Querying Hibernate Envers revision by revision date

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have started using Hibernate Envers for audit logging business objects.
I have read the documentation and from all the examples i have seen, querying is done by revision number.

I would like to query by revision date, i.e. get all the rows of an audited entity the happened at a specific date or date range.
I such a thing possible?

My revinfo table holds a timestamp so i know the data is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is of course possible. You simply need to get the revision numbers corresponding to the dates.

This is possible either by directly querying the revision table, or using the `AuditReader.getRevisionForDate` method.

Answer (score 5):

Use the audit reader and add query params for your dates.  The property is called *timestamp*.  This example uses an inclusive start date and an exclusive end date.

```
 List<Object[]> revisions = (List<Object[]>) getAuditReader().createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(YourEntityClass.class, false, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").ge(startDate))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionProperty("timestamp").lt(endDate))
                .getResultList();
```

Comment: Hi. This returns multiple versions of the entity if it was modified in the same date. Doo we have to filter it ex-post or is there any AuditReader method that can help me?

Comment: May you can just add more criteria to narrow down your search.  Do you have an incremental id in your record?  That might be a good way to get the latest.